# Best way to allow NullPointerException when null analysis is turned on

Tags: java, eclipse, nullpointerexception, eclipse-jdt

In Java JDT plugin for Eclipse, there is an option to turn on errors and warnings for null pointer issues. You can annotate your code to indicate whether a field, variable, parameter, or return value can be null or not.

The problem is this. If you enable this feature and enable Errors for Null pointer access and mark a field as possibly null

```
   private @Nullable SomeClass _delegate;
```

but you actually WANT particular accesses of this field to generate a NullPointerException if null:

```
   /**
    * @throws NullPointerException if delegate is null
    */
   void someMethod()
   {
       _delegate.someMethod();
   }
```

As written, I can't do this because the JDT gives me a "potential null pointer" error. The JDT does not provide any way to suppress errors (as far as I know).

I can lower the severity of this error to warning and then suppress it, or I could explicitly check for null and manually throw a NullPointerException. Is there some other good way around this problem?

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to use the Objects.requireNonNull method that was introduced in Java 7. This will do an explicit null check, so I could write:

```
Objects.requireNonNull(_delegate).someMethod();
```

I am not sure whether or not the JVM is smart enough to optimize this call away at runtime. So for performance critical code, you may want to profile when using this technique.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I find the NPE one of the least helpful Exceptions, often wished it would at least give the name of the variable that was being accessed and was null. That being said, and given my general aversion to them, I would probably replace the NullPointerException with an IllegalStateException in your scenario.

Other than that, I think dropping the severity to warning as you have already said yourself is the most logical way. This may be my personal preference speaking, but to me a compile error is the compiler telling me "what you have done absolutely won't work" - that's why it goes on strike when it finds one. With null accesses, however, the compiler usually can't be sure, except in some construed cases - it even says it's a *potential* null access. So having this as a warning instead of an error makes more sense anyway.

Not at my most eloquent this morning so tl;dr: Errors="fatal", warnings="you'll live (barely)", potential null access isn't fatal, so drop it to warning.

Comment: I am not sure that an IllegalStateException would be that much more informative than a NPE, and if I have to manually throw I can create a more useful error message. There are several reasons to prefer a NPE: (1) you may be overriding a method that is explicitly documented to throw a NPE under the applicable conditions (2) the JVM will generate one for you, so you don't have to bloat your code with extra throw calls.

Comment: I agree that it is not so bad to make this a warning instead of an error since our practice is generally to avoid checking in code with either, but marking it as an error would be preferable. It is unfortunate that the JDT does not provide a way to suppress errors that only exist in the JDT such as this one.

Comment: You're right about being more descriptive in self-thrown messages, of course. I think I expressed myself badly, all I meant was if I go down the road of throwing an exception myself, the NPE is never the one I would go with (unless of course, as you said, bound by an exisiting API I'm overriding). Another (ugly) way to solve your problem would be to disable the null access option whenever you want to check in. I imagine that would become fairly tedious though if you work with fine grained commits.